# Login as root over SSH without knowing the password (sudo -s)?

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

I SSH to a server with:

```
ssh user@host
```

and then I change to the root user with:

```
sudo -s
```

providing my own password NOT the root user password - as I understand this works because I am in the sudoers file.

Is there anyway to SSH/login and switch to the root user in one step even though I don't have the root user password?

The point being that I would like to avoid typing my password two times

Comment: Sure thing, simply register an SSH key in the `root` account, set `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` in `sshd_config`, restart the SSH server (e.g. `service ssh restart`) and log on directly as `root`. Avoid using password authentication with SSH, especially whenever it concerns a sudoer or the superuser itself.

Comment: Note that if your SSH server is externally available (e.g., accessible from outside your local network), devices *will* try to connect to it as 'root'. As @0xC0000022L writes, it's not a good idea to allow password authentication (really at all, but especially for a sudoer/root). The thought of devices continuously trying to connect as root worries me (even though I use pubkey authentication), so I don't allow root login, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @singalongconflict I think the worry is justified, however personally I am using a tarpit approach implemented via Netfilter and IP sets, so that potential attackers have a fairly hard time to brute-force _anything_. The IP sets allow entries to time out, so I am safeguarded against locking myself out. For `root`, if you allow it with key authentication, perhaps it's a good idea to limit access to particular IPs or IP ranges ... or use the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 easy ways to achieve this:

1. You allow the **root** user to login through ssh, you can do this by editing the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and setting the `PermitRootLogin` to **true**, this will allow root to connect through ssh.
2. You create a custom script for your ssh user to automatically login as root. This can be done through the `/etc/passwd` file, you will notice your user will look something like :

`your_user:x:1001:1001:Oqhax,,,:/home/your_user:/bin/bash`

To run a custom script on login, you would change the `/bin/bash` portion and add your own script that will run whatever code you want, this can include something like sudo -s and then at the end of your custom script you can also call `/bin/bash` again I believe, so your `passwd` would look something like:

```
your_user:x:1001:1001:Oqhax,,,:/home/your_user:/bin/your_script
```

Beware that the second option will impact your ssh login behaviour, so for you to test this, make sure that you can deal with making a mistake and effectively being unable to log in with your user, so make sure you have a backdoor ssh access through another user or root as mentioned in option 1 at least temporarily for you to log back in and correct any mistakes until you have the setup working.

**Update:** Following up on comments below, it is worth mentioning this does not only affect the ssh login but any login of that user (I've approached this assuming that your requirement is for this user always to login as root and you don't wish to allow the actual root user to log in through ssh). It is also worth noting that this is as easier solution to what could be a much tighter and complex one that would apply to SSH only, your question doesn't go into a lot of detail.

As mentioned in the comments, you could also achieve this same behaviour through `/etc/ssh/sshrc` I just prefer to edit the raw /etc/passwd so that in the future it is very evident what is happening and it requires you to accomodate for the consequences, while `sshrc` is great but makes future troubleshooting a litle harder if you happen to forget how you have set up the system which let's be honest, happens a lot.
But it is indeed a good habit to have to not expose the root user at all, this will give you much more flexibility in the future and to try things and to custom your sudoer permissions.

Hope this helps

Comment: `authorized_keys`, `sshrc` all sensible means to achieve it, equally it could be done with `pam_exec`. But your approach does it unconditionally and completely neglects `/etc/shells`. Even matching the username with `Match` in `sshd_config` and applying `ForceCommand` to run whatever command is needed to impersonate `root` could do this _unconditionally_ for SSH connections only. Your method affects _everything_, not just SSH connections. -1.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, my intention was to provide an easy solution to someone who is quite obviously not very experienced with linux, it is worth mentioning this poses security concerns but it is a quick and easy way to get it working if we are taling about a device or solution that doesn't require much security. The moethod I proposed is simply to provide an alternative to the default bash on login adn to provide his own script and "control" the login behaviour of a particular user, ssh or not yes. I don't consider it an awful solution even though there are other ones

Comment: His question also mentions .... anyway to SSH/login .... I assumed he meant "ssh login / console login"